# Issue with z-index on element in a div with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a strange issue with the z-index of an element not getting set even when I put a position:absolute on it. The parent element has overflow:hidden set.

TO see an example of what I mean:

1. Go to http://www.berrisforda.com/
2. On the job search tab there is a custom select/dropdown hover over it
3. Notice that it get cut off by the container, it actually extends below it but the container has overflow:hidden set

I am trying to set a z-index on it but haven't had any luck

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the hieght on your .tab to be shorter...

```
ul#output li.tab {
position: absolute;
width: 684px;
height: 345px; /*see how I changed this value*/
background-color: #fff;
}
```

And remove overflow:hidden from #feature-list{}

And set the z-index:1 on .dropdown dd ul {}

**Do the following step too to fix you footer....**

Sorry Burt - I made a mistake initially - here is the final step

Remove position:relative and z-index from #footer

Then you should be good to go!

Answer (score 5):

In this case, `z-index` won't help you. If you have `overflow:hidden` on a parent element, any child outside of that element's bounding box will be hidden. You have three options:

1. Move the drop down element so that it is no longer a child of the `overflow:hidden` element.
2. Make the drop down list scroll.
3. Remove the `overflow:hidden` style.